# To convert image by image magic in php

Tags: php, imagemagick

I have to convert a gif image to png image. For which i have tried this. The image file is in folder ( localhost ).

I have tried the below code.

```
$imageFile = "14981180607.gif";
$temp = sys_get_temp_dir();
file_put_contents($temp, file_get_contents($imageFile) );

exec("convert ".escapeshellarg($temp)." img/xx_%05d.png");
```

I need the image to be converted and store in my img folder, which i mentioned the path.

Comment: that code is not working or do you have any error in output ?

Comment: This is not working

Comment: You do know that you can use [copy()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php) instead of reading the file contents and putting it in a new file manually?

Comment: Also, you're saving the new file with the name of the temp _directory_.

Comment: Can you please elaborate the thing you want to say. Because i am new in php and i want to know the use of image magic in this.

Comment: try convert path/to/image.gif /any/path/image.png

Comment: The function `sys_get_temp_dir()` return the path to the temp _directory_. If you want to get a temp _file_, you need to use: `$temp = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'image')`.

Comment: I am very sorry. It is permission issue. Thank you for your help.